# Crtl-C does not kill AppArmour and namespace sandboxed process

Tags: namespace, apparmor

Given this AppArmour profile (intended to avoid manipulation of git repositories):

```
/RISC_OS {
  signal,
  ptrace,
  unix,
  network,

  / mrixwlk,
  /** mrixwlk,
  deny /**/.git** wl,
  deny /**/refs/ wl,

}
```

And this example namespace sandbox:

```
bwrap --ro-bind /bin /bin --ro-bind /lib /lib --ro-bind /usr /usr --ro-bind /bin/sleep /RISC_OS --unshare-all --die-with-parent --as-pid-1 /RISC_OS 60
```

When pressing Ctrl-C the `sleep` command under the name `/RISC_OS` continues sleeping, rather than terminating as expected. Without either the AppArmour profile of the `--as-pid-1` option it terminates as required.